# Is it good practice to print paypal's transaction ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, invoice

Would it be good practice to have paypal's transaction ID on a customers invoice?

I have a invoice with an order number from my own system and i was wondering if it is usefull to have paypal's transaction ID on the invoice as well?

ps: I  realise i don't have code in my question but even paypal directs to stackoverflow, see footer https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

Comment: The user himself can get that id from his paypal page or not?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal uses a different transaction ID for each user, so your customer's transaction ID would be different.

Comment: huh? I assume each transaction has an unique ID as will every paypal user has an unique identifier. I am looking just for a right way to design a bill/invoice for accounting purpose and I am questioning if i should "print"  the transaction id on the pdf besides the Buyers name, address and country.

Comment: Will you be using the PayPal Invoice API?  If so, the invoice ID and Invoice Number would be acceptable to display and should match between both parties.